# PHP & XML (PT) Time Format

Tags: php, xml, date, dateinterval

I'm writing a PHP script to parse an XML file generated from software our company uses. The time format is formatted in such a way; I am wondering whether their is an easier way to parse the time.

```
<duration>PT1H23M5S</duration> // This is the XML format
```

I have a script to parse it but I feel it may be too long and more complicated than it needs to be:

```
    if( strpos($duration, "H") == false ) {
      $duration = substr_replace($duration, "00:", 0, 0);
    }
$duration = preg_replace("#PT#", "", $duration);
$duration = preg_replace("#H#", ":", $duration);
$duration = preg_replace("#M#", ":", $duration);
$duration = preg_replace("#S#", "", $duration);

// Prepare to process values under 10 (add trailing 0)
list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(":", $duration);
if($hour < 10 and $hour != "00") {
    $hour = substr_replace($hour, "0", 0, 0); // adds a 0 behind digit EG 09 H
}
if($minute < 10) {
    $minute = substr_replace($minute, "0", 0, 0);
}
if($second < 10 and $second > 0) {
    $second = substr_replace($second, "0", 0, 0);
}
if($second == "") {
    $second = "00";
}
$duration = $hour . ":" . $minute . ":" . $second;
```

**Thanks in advance for any replies!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class.

```
$d = new DateInterval($duration);
echo $d->format('%h hours, %i minutes, %S seconds');
```